# Plugin dynamic title using WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm trying to make a small plugin for my blog ([WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)), but I have the following two problems.

1. I want from the plugin to take the latest three posts from a custom category, but now it takes only the last one and duplicates it three times. How can I fix that?
2. I want to make a dynamic title. That means that I want to be able to change the title of the plugin from the admin control panel. How can I accomplish that?

UPDATE:

Thanks to you people I managed to display the post image, but it doesn't displaying in the right spot.

This is the proper HTML

```
<li>
    <div class="projects">
        <ul class="projects sticker">
            <li><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></li>
            <li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</li>
```

This is how it's displaying now

```
<li>
    <div class="projects">
         <ul class="projects sticker">
             <li><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></li>
             <li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
```

Basically I have to put the img tag inside the list and div.

Here is my code so far

```
$args = array('numberposts' => '3', 'category' => $cat_id);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
foreach ($recent_posts as $recent ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look   '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'
    .'<li>' .'<div class="projects-wrapper">' .'<ul class="projects-sticker">'       .'<li>' .'<h2>' .   $recent["post_title"] .'</li>' .'</h2>' .'<li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li></ul>' .'<img src="'.the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail').'" />'  .'</div>' .'</li>'.'</a>';
```

Comment: Do print_r($rand_posts) and your see your 3 posts, but what your doing is just repeating the same content. while the foreach loops over the result of thos 3 posts

Comment: Can you make yourself more clear. I'm sorry, but php is not my strong side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get recent post better use [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts). Here is the snippet of it.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3','category' => $cat_id );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail');
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: You still have the `numberposts` as a invalid argument it has to be `posts_per_page`

Comment: @janw - Check the refrence function in the link provided I above. It is `numberposts`. While `post_per_page` is correct for `query_posts`.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem remains. It shows the last post duplicated 3 times

Comment: Not sure but try to `wp_reset_query();` after your loop. I have updated my answer. Or give us some debug details.

Comment: Yes ! Success. One more little problem though, how can i add a image properly. I've tried with the_post_thumbnail(), but nothing was displayed

Comment: Use `get_the_post_thumbnail`. Updated my answer with use of the same.

Comment: use `the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail')` without echo, that will also work. Do keep in mind a featured image has to be set

Comment: @user2013488 - It's not good way to keep updating your question. Better ask a new question for new problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Ordering posts**

You use `showposts => 3` That is not a valid arg use `posts_per_page => 3`, remove the `numberposts`.
Also you order random: `'orderby' => 'rand'` that has to be `'orderby' => 'date'`
More arguments can be found on the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page.

So use:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => $cat_id);
```

**Widget title**

Check out the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), extend the widget class and add your field in the `form` function. That way you can also make the number of posts variable for example.

Comment: Which problem of the 3? BTW in your code I see `category` without quotes. I hope you do have that right in your code?